# What is the meaning of 'static as a function constraint?

Tags: rust, lifetime

What is the meaning of static in this context?

`fn foo<F: Human + 'static>(param: F) {}`

```
fn main() {
    let kate = Kate { age: 30 };
    foo(kate);
}
```

I understand marking `global_variable` `static` is similar to what static means ie. in c#, space for the variable is allocated in a separate segment of the memory, existing for the whole execution of the program.

```
static global_variable: i32 = 5;
```

But what I don't understand what giving 'static constraint means. Is `kate` somehow promoted, and her lifetime extended so it now lives for the whole execution of program too?

Or does it simply mean it'll be deallocated as soon as `foo` stops using it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Putting a constraint like `T: 'a` means that all lifetime parameters of the type `T` must satisfy the lifetime constraint `'a` (thus, must outlive it).

For example, if I have this struct:

```rust
struct Kate<'a, 'b> {
    address: &'a str,
    lastname: &'b str
}
```

`Kate<'a, 'b>` will satisfy the constraint `F: Human + 'static` only if `'a == 'static` **and** `'b == 'static`.

However, a struct without any lifetime parameter will always satisfy any lifetime constraint.

So as a summary, a constraint like `F: 'static` means that either:

- `F` has no lifetime parameter
- all lifetime parameters of `F` are `'static`